# Login authentication for user, guardian and teacher

Tags: laravel

My system requires login for `user`, `teacher`, and `guardian`. I did a little bit of research on the topic and lot of folks talk about utilizing the `user type` feature. But I don't think that will work for me or maybe **I don't understand how to make it work that way**.

One thing I'm concern about when I'm creating a teacher(something only the admin should do) is that  a teacher can teach multiple subjects and classes. So, in  short a many to many relationship exists between teacher and subject. Whenever I inserting a teacher I have to specify the class(es) he/she teaches. 
Also a guardian is related to many students, and whenever I'm inserting a guardian I have to specify the student(s) the guardian is related to.

I could create separate migrations, models controllers, and views for all those users(admins, guardians, staffs and teachers) but something tells me that wouldn't be an efficient solution to the problem. What are others alternatives to addressing the issue.

What are others alternatives to addressing this issue, wherein I can have a single login that is use to authenticate different kinds of users and **returns views that are specific to user kind**.

Is there a way that when the administrator is inserting teacher and guardians a user account be generated for them?
Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are creating a user (any type of user) you can set their type with a column in the user table like there is a column in the user table user_type.

this column will work like flag value 1 for admin, 2 for a teacher , 3 for parents and etc like this.

now whenever your user will login you can set that data in session or if you use AUTH in laraval you can easily get that in your controller, view where you want 
like this Auth::user()->user_type

so now I have something to compare against each other so by some little bit condition you can easily set what a user needs to depend on his/her type.

if all users depend on only type than this way is good enough, but if you want to set various permission to a different user or the different type of user then you need access control system. there are many package available now

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust i find this good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup manyToMany relation between `User` and `User`.

Then you can check if the user is student or guardian by checking if the pivot table row exists. It's the same for `User` - `Subject` relation.

For example the pivot table can be called `guardian_studnet` and it can have two fields in it: `guardian_id` and `student_id` which both will be pointing to `users` table `id` column.

In this scenario the same user can be a student and a guardian though I'm not sure how necessary this is.

Don't forget to index the pivot table fields and as further optimization you can add the `teacher`,`student` booleans in your `User` model. But this will require for you to update this fields whenever the relation status changes. Not sure about the gain though.

Check out the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: What do you mean that I need to setup a manyToMany relationship between `User` and `User`?